# Renaming Uploaded Image

Tags: php

I have an upload field for a single image and I am trying to get it to rename the image when it uploads

if user uploads image called picture.jpg

it will rename it O1CCJDSXBOM2.jpg

```
$file = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$file_loc = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['photo']['size'];
$folder = "../uploads/";
```

Comment: $target_dir = "..uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . "O1CCJDSXBOM2.jpg";
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)

Comment: well... have your read [w3schools tutorial regarding file upload](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) and read [move_uploaded_file](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_move_uploaded_file.asp)?

Comment: everything works fine it uploads I just need to rename it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Upload you can rename like this

```
$target_dir = "..uploads/"; 
$target_file = $target_dir."O1CCJDSXBOM2.jpg"; 
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)
```

`move_uploaded_file`(first parameter is your uploaded file , second paramter is where you want to move the file with file name `ex: uploads/O1CCJDSXBOM2.jpg`  )

**security note :**

1) Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

2) Check if file already exists

3) Check file size

4) Allow certain file formats

5) Check file size

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to rename the uploaded file with the original name, try something like this:

```
$tmp_filename = realpath($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
if ($_FILES['upload']['error'] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] . "<br />" . $_FILES['upload']['error'][$i];
} else {
  $new_filename = realpath("../uploads") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES['upload']['name'];

  if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_filename, $new_filename)) {
      echo "file moved to " . $new_filename;
  } else {
      echo "error moving uploaded file.";
  }
}
```

See [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for more information, especially security.